# 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'lower' - When I run python3 manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

I am running a web application(wagtail cms) on linux ubuntu.  I am getting this error when I run python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Please see the error message on the console.

```
  Performing system checks...

  System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
  March 22, 2018 - 15:27:33
  Django version 1.11.1, using settings 'ntdl.settings'
  Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
  Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
  Internal Server Error: /
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
  packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", 
  line 138, in __call__
  response = self.process_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
  packages/django/middleware/security.py", line 25, in process_request
  host = self.redirect_host or request.get_host()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/request.py", line 
   105, in get_host
  if domain and validate_host(domain, allowed_hosts):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/request.py", line 
   579, in validate_host
  if pattern == '*' or is_same_domain(host, pattern):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/http.py", line 
  291, in is_same_domain
  pattern = pattern.lower()
  AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'lower'
  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 11959
  Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
  packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", 
  line 138, in __call__
  response = self.process_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
  packages/django/middleware/security.py", line 25, in process_request
  host = self.redirect_host or request.get_host()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/request.py", line 
  105, in get_host
  if domain and validate_host(domain, allowed_hosts):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/request.py", line 
  579, in validate_host
  if pattern == '*' or is_same_domain(host, pattern):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/http.py", line 
  291, in is_same_domain
   pattern = pattern.lower()
   AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'lower'
  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 11965
```

I had gone inside the http.py checked the code it has code below

```
 def is_same_domain(host, pattern):
 """
 Return ``True`` if the host is either an exact match or a match
 to the wildcard pattern.

 Any pattern beginning with a period matches a domain and all of its
 subdomains. (e.g. ``.example.com`` matches ``example.com`` and
 ``foo.example.com``). Anything else is an exact string match.
 """
 if not pattern:
    return False

  pattern = pattern.lower()
  return (
     pattern[0] == '.' and (host.endswith(pattern) or host == pattern[1:]) 
   or
    pattern == host
  )
```

I am not able see any errors here.  Please help me in fixing this error.

With Many Thanks,

Bharath AK

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger to see what's causing `pattern` to be set to `Ellipsis`?

Comment: For me the error is in the caller function: I think you submit `pattern` to `is_same_domain` which is not a string. Without such code, we cannot help.  You can test by printing `pattern` at beginning of the function.

Comment: seems like `type(pattern)` is not `str`

Comment: I had tried print its value it has test_site and test_site2  how can test the calling part  Please suggest me.  with many thanks Bharath AK

Comment: Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
pattern
test_site
pattern
test_site2
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 138, in __call__
    response = self.process_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/security.py", line 25, in process_request

Comment: sorry I had print after pattern.lower.  Now I added print before pattern.lower the log is below  pattern
test_site
pattern
test_site2
pattern
Ellipsis
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for suggesting ideas.  I had searched the test_site and test_site2 in the project.  I found ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['test_site', 'test_site2', ...]  this value is read at http.py and it is throwing error.  once I changed '*' this error got vanished. it throw some other error.  I will raise that in another question  Thank you all for your ideas.  With regards, Bharath AK

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too much Django experience but when I had this problem, with the below code:

```
@api_view([...])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def blog_list(request):
    return Response('successfull attempt')
```

but just by removing the [...] in @api_view decorator, the problem is solved.

```
@api_view()
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def blog_list(request):
    return Response('successfull attempt')
```

Answer (score -1):

AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'predict'

for this error you just try the encoder_features = autoencoder.predict() immediate after defining autoencoder you get no error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please include additional details for your answer, don't just submit code. E.g. explain why you think this is the optimal solution.